# Are heavy damage and light damage mutually exclusive?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

At first, I was putting bonus % damage against lightly wounded targets on all my gear, under the assumption that anyone who is damaged would count.

I.E., if you stab me once, I'm bleeding a bit. Stab me twice, and I'm bleeding heavily - but I'm still bleeding a bit...right? In Amalur, maybe not.

So my question is, do "lightly wounded" and "heavily wounded" act as mutually exclusive states, akin to bonus damage during day/night? Or are heavy wounds simply a continuation of the lightly wounded state, akin to real-wirld logic?

Comment: I always figured it is mostly due to health % losage. So like under 50% of health you are heavily wounded and above you are lightly wounded. Just like day and night. Not sure about this tho

Comment: I've always assumed they were mutually exclusive. I'd quite like to know the answer to this too.

Comment: With the quiet surrounding both this question and my question about critical hits, I feel like the hardcore number-crunchers and theorycrafters from the Skyrim tag do not play Amalur, lol.

Comment: It's not that we (skyrimmers) don't play Amalur, it's that number crunching in Amalur isn't a compelling aspect compared to the action of combat.  If I were to guess, the states would be exclusive, the same way day and night are exclusive - but that's just a guess.

Comment: Like SaintWacko, I would assume them to be mutually exclusive. If lightly wounded was a blanket for all wounded, why would they specify that the effect would only work against *lightly* wounded targets rather than just say, "bonus % damage against wounded targets?"

Comment: That's solid logic, @skovacs1 - even if not a "for sure" answer, it's a perfectly good Occam's Razor answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer on the KoA boards might help ya: http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?6582-what-are-lightly-wounded-targets-Gem-question-I-think.  Summarizing: it does sound like they are mutually exclusive states.  What's not clear is where the dividing line(s) are for lightly wounded and heavily wounded...seems like lightly wounded is about 75% health or so.